# Abrir actividad reciente al volver a abrir la aplicación

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Saludos, soy nuevo en el foro y en el  ambito del desarrollo de aplicaciones Android, bueno, mas bien he desarrollado muy pocas aplicaciones sencillas pero nada complicado, en este momento me encuentro creando un app un poco mas completa con WS, Sqlite y diferentes actividades, me encuentro atorado con una parte de la aplicacion y me gustaria saber si me pudieran orientar a resolverlo.

Mi duda es la siguiente.
Tengo un app que tiene 3 actividades, lo que quisiera saber es como puedo hacer para guardar los datos de la segunda actividad en caso de que la aplicacion se cierre inesperadamente y que al volver a iniciar la aplicacion se abra la segunda actividad y que tenga los datos que estaban en la misma.
Ejemplo.
En mi segunda actividad tengo una serie de ToggleButtons que al ser pulsados muestran datos que fueron traidos de la primera actividad y un Button normal para regresar a la actividad principal, supongamos que se le acaba la pila al celular y se apaga, lo quiero que haga mi aplicacion es que al volver a iniciar la app, en lugar de iniciar con la actividad principal me abra mi segunda acitivdad donde tengo los Togglebuttons con la informacion que tenia en el momento que se apago el telefono.

Tengo entendido que se ocupa una clase llamada SharedPreferences para guardar datos y volverlos a leer y que en los metodos onDestroy y oOnStart se mandan a llamar los metodos donde se guardaron y se leyeron los datos almacenados. 
Pero no tengo entendido como puedo hacer para que se abra mi segunda actividad al volver a iniciar mi aplicacion.
De antemano es agradezco la ayuda ya sea poca o a tal grado de resolver mis dudas.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) para guardar que actividad abrir cuando regresas, pero debe tener una actividad de inicio desde donde se abriría cualquiera de las 3, por ejemplo:

```
  //Se obtiene el valor guardado en la preferencia, para saber cual de las 3 abrir:
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("MISPREFERENCIAS", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int myActividad = sp.getInt("actividad", 0);

//Se realiza un intent para abrir la Actividad :
  Intent myIntent;  

switch(myActividad){
    case 0:// abre Actividad 0
    myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Actividad0.class);
    startActivity(myIntent);
    break;
    case 1:// abre Actividad 1
    myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Actividad1.class);
    startActivity(myIntent);
    break;
    case 2: // abre Actividad 2
    myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Actividad2.class);
    startActivity(myIntent);
    break;    
 }

//Puedes usar finish() para cerrar rapidamente la actividad que abre la que guardaste!
finish();
```

Y como comentas puedes usar `onPause()` u `onStop()` para guardar los datos:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    //Guarda datos a preferencia o Base de datos.
    super.onPause();
}
```

y `onStart()` para cargarlos:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    //Carga datos de preferencia o Base de datos.
    super.onStart();
}
```